# Removendo strings de dentro de uma lista

Tags: python, lista, xls

Olá eu tenho uma lista que recebo de um arquivo `xls` através da biblioteca `xlrd`

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Videos\CSV\produtos_filtrado.xls") # Escolhe o arquivo a ser lido.

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0) #Escolha a aba a ser lida. 

for i in range(1,worksheet.nrows): #itere sobre os itens da aba 
    lista = worksheet.row(i)
    print(lista)
```

o resultado do `print`:

```
[text:'2746', text:'8512.20.21', text:'2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', text:'SL-121410', text:'6949999876781']
[text:'2747', text:'8512.20.21', text:'2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', text:'SL-121410CR', text:'6949999876798']
[text:'2794', text:'8512.20.21', text:'2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', text:'SL-121510', text:'6949999876811']
[text:'2795', text:'8512.20.21', text:'2 - Estrangeira - Adquirida no mercado interno, exceto a indicada no código 7', text:'SL-043210', text:'6949999876804']
```

como é possível observar existe um `text:` antes dos dados que preciso, minha pergunta é tem como remover esse `text:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É que assim você está criando uma lista de objetos do XLRD, faça desta maneira para recuperar apenas os valores:

```py
lista = list()
for i in range(1,worksheet.nrows):
    lista.append(
        [j.value for j in worksheet.row(i)]
    )

print(lista)
```

E ele montará a lista somente com os valores de cada célula.

Comment: eu so tenho uma duvida esse for deixa o ultimo valor na lista? sabe o por que?

Comment: Hmmm, é que me baseei no teu exemplo, fiz uma edição na resposta e agora resolve o problema.

Comment: Agora entendi muito obrigado